# How do I add include directories in a c++ project in Eclipse Che?

Tags: docker, include, eclipse-che

I'm trying to use Eclipse Che as an IDE to develop a C++ application on a remote linux machine.
Che can access the source code on the host system because of the

```
-v <LOCAL_PATH>:/data
```

part when running the docker container.
But how am I supposed to access include directories (and later libraries to link with)?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: why did you remove the c++ tag?
Eclipse Che seems to support c++ development, but I haven't found any documentation on how to use it, so I am specifically interested in how to set up a c++ development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this on Kubernetes? In that case, you are not just exporting the source code volume, the remote Linux machine *is* your workspace.

I'm afraid I'm not sure how you would do this with Che in Docker without jumping through some hoops.

Comment: No kubernetes. Just plain vanilla docker. My problem is: my local work computer is a windows machine. But I have to develop a linux microservice in c++ running on a remote machine. I am not very efficient when coding in vi, so I was looking for a way to use an IDE without having to install a desktop environment on the remote machine.